How to use the Leaflet on React Native and also to have a marker and the routing mechanism
We were using the Google maps and API's for the mobile app, but considering the cost for API's in picture we would like to explore the Leaflet in react application. Can someone help to find some good resource or helpful link to accomplish the task.
Thanks in advance.
We tried OpenStreetMap and we could see the routing but it looks like it was not a shortest path. So we would like to try leaflet as well.
